# Over voltage protection without shorting the Output to GND during Over voltage

Tags: zener, schottky, over-voltage-protection, ptc

Here is the circuit diagram i am referring.

[image: Circuit referring to]

Vin_12v_ext - Max 12V;

Batt_V = max 5.4V;

Vin_ext_12v_gen is either Vin_12v_ext or batt_v;

5v_reg - is either generated by an on board regulator or switched from batt_v via M7 & D4.;

This circuitry is used to switch board power from Primary(Vin_12v_ext) to battery(batt_v).

M1 is the primary leg which switches power from Primary power source.

M2 & M3 are secondary leg which switches power from Secondary power source.

Whole board is powered by Vin_ext_12v_gen rail(which can be Vin_12V_ext or batt_v).

Few other regulators are powered by 5V_REG net on the right top.

Issue faced was, When Vin_12V_ext is OFF, we are seeing batt_v on Vin_ext_12v_gen net as expected. But when Vin_12v_ext power came back, Vin_12v_ext flows to 5VREG net via M1,M2 and D4 which is damaging regulators(whose max input voltage is 5.5V) on 5VREG net.

I can't change any architecture of this,

So, i am trying to add high speed PTC+Zenar diode protection at the Output of 5VREG net to Protect the regulators on the downside of 5VREG net.

But i saw PTC+Zenar approach to protect against Over voltages is used normally at the entrance of the power to the whole board. I **have not** seen PTC+Zenar approach inside of the boards power architecture.

Whether we can use PTC+Zenar/Schottky diode approach to limit Voltage on 5VREG net to 5V?

Comment: *But when Vin_12v_ext power came back, Vin_12v_ext flows to 5VREG net via M1,M2 and D4 which is damaging regulators* Does M2 survive when its body diode is used to charge the 5V battery with this 12V?

Comment: @Huisman: for current testing we have just connected a DC Power supply at batt_v net, we see OVP error flag on Power supply when this event happens. M2 is working fine.

Comment: So, M2 will get damaged when a real battery is connected!

Comment: @Huisman: Vin_12V_ext can give max ~6A, which can handled by M2 easily for short time few mS. i am sure that there is no threat to M2. we are handling this event with multiple options, so, that transient will not reach M2 at all. If on worst case if it reaches M2_M3_D if by some means that transient is arrested for few 10's mS, board is safe.

Comment: Oops... I was referring to the wrong mosfet. I mean **M3**. When the Vin_12v_ext power is available, Vin_12v_ext flows via M1,M2 through the body diode of M3 to the 5V battery, *contineously*.

Comment: @Huisman: I am referring to 5V_reg net in attached schematic, whether other regulators are connected(not shown in schematic) whose max input voltage is ~6V. Those needs to be protected. for protecting batt_v net from Vin_12v_ext we are just adding a schottky diode in reverse.

Comment: As an update, i am going with PTC+Zener combination (PolyZen from Littlefuse).